# How to watch for 12th confirmation with web3 filters

Tags: web3js, filters

It doesn't seem possible to update the options in web3.eth.filter() dynamically, so how would one watch for a transaction involving a particular account appearing on the 12th latest block?

Comment: Esiest way is to subscribe to every block and in the callback use a filter and the synchronous get function to obtain only the past 12th block's events. Does this match your need?

Comment: How do you mean _subscribe_?

Comment: Use the eth.filter('latest', callback) to be notified for every new block being added to the chain. Spend some time in the API. Good luck.

Comment: Ended up with [this code](https://gist.github.com/pau1m/4a3550689bb072ae937266e366755d20). Feels clunky but it works.

Comment: You could simplify as the eth.getBlock does work synchronously if no callback is supplied. But otherwise it is ok

Answer (score 5):

Answering own question.

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))

let account = '0x05430f5201585c2601bb75d9658007202864c993'
let filter = web3.eth.filter('latest')
filter.watch(function(error, result) {
  if (!error) {
    let confirmedBlock = web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber - 11)
    if (confirmedBlock.transactions.length > 0) {
      confirmedBlock.transactions.forEach(function(txId) {
        let transaction = web3.eth.getTransaction(txId)
        if (transaction.to == account) {
          // Do something useful.
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It could be simplified a bit. First, try to fetch transactionReceipt (`web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txId)`). It's possible only when it was mined. In response you should find block number. Make diff from `blockNumber-txBlock` if it's greater then 12 it definitely confirmed :)

Btw, I've read somehwere that waiting for 8 blocks should be enough.

Comment: There was a network fork between `geth` and Parity clients in Nov 24 2016 where "~165 blocks were mined on the now abandoned chain". See https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/25/security-alert-11242016-consensus-bug-geth-v1-4-19-v1-5-2/ .

Comment: @radmen the initial intention was to watch for a transaction to a particular account on a specific block, so have no way of knowing in advance with the transaction id would be. Have updated the original question to make that clearer

Comment: @grift00 ah, now it's more clear :) Thanks for update!

Comment: It appears that `web3.eth.filter` has been replaced with [`web3.eth.subscribe`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth-subscribe.html#eth-subscribe).